# привести тип integer к date нельзя

Tags: sql, postgresql

Делаю запрос к БД postgresql. Как тогда дату необходимо написать, чтобы он за integer не считал? Почему он мне выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  привести тип integer к date нельзя
LINE 3:   and start_date > cast(2020-03-12 AS date)
```

Код

```
select * from contract 
WHERE id = 6
  and start_date > CAST(2020-03-12 AS date)
  and start_date < cast(2020-03-19 as date) + interval '1' day
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я догадался. Одинарные кавычки ведь нужно поставить, а в них дату

```
select * from contract 
WHERE id = 6
  and start_date > cast('2020-03-12' as date)
  and start_date < cast('2020-03-19' as date) + interval '1' day
```